# ¿python.exe o py.exe en Windows?

Tags: python, django, windows

Estoy usando Python 2.7 en un entorno virtual, pero no me dejar correr la consola de python de manera normal sino que:

- en lugar de usar `python manage.py runserver`
- debo usar `py manage.py runserver`

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe?

Comment: Asi se llama tu ejecutable. Es importante conocer tu sistema operativo y la distribución de Python que estás usando. Por otro lado, ¿te funciona usando `py` o cuál sería el problema real?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no hay problema de desarrollo que resolver.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que entiendo, estás usando Windows, [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) se menciona que py es un lanzador empleado en Windows; puedes colocar `py -h` para obtener la lista de argumentos.

Si quieres crear un alias de py, entiendo que con la instrucción `doskey python=py` lo tendrías hecho, claro eso sólo crea el alias en la sesión de consola actual (al volver a ejecutar la consola de MS-DOS deberías volver a ejecutar el comando doskey). Una alternativa que podrías intentar es buscar el archivo py.exe y cambiarle el nombre a python.exe, aunque no sé si con ello generarías problemas a otro software que se base en la existencia de un py.exe.